# Cyrillic chars inside of UrlRewriting.config

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco

Hello I need use Cyrillic chars inside of UrlRewriting.config

Does any one know how to do it in correct way ?
If i write Cyrillic chars directly I got error. if I use code like %D1 %82 %D1 %83 it doesn't work.

Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use Cyrillic characters in the config file, use the character entity code instead. This way, you won't need to fiddle around with the encoding of the config file. I don't know Cyrillic so I'm just going to use a random string of characters for demonstration.

For example, if you want to change the url `~/БДЯ/Л.aspx` to `~/new-БДЯ/Л.aspx`, apply the following:

```xml
<add name="datafolderrewrite" 
    virtualUrl="^~/&#1041;&#1044;&#1071;/(.*).aspx" 
    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
    destinationUrl="~/new-&#1041;&#1044;&#1071;/$1.aspx" 
    ignoreCase="true" />
```

I used the following page to detemine the respective entity codes: http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/cyrillicchart.html